# fetchAll Only returns one row, but counts all? Symfony / Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mautic

I am trying to return an array result from a query - but I'm only getting the first row back.

The count returns 5 (which is the number of the rows that matches the query) - what am I missing in order to display those?

```
    public function getFailType($email)
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();
    $q->select('dnc.comments, count(dnc.reason) as total')
        ->from(MAUTIC_TABLE_PREFIX.'lead_donotcontact', 'dnc')
        ->where('dnc.channel_id = :channelId')
        ->groupBy('dnc.comments')
        ->setParameter('channelId', $email);

    $results = $q->execute()->fetchAll();
            $count = count($results);
    $dnc     = isset($results) ? $results[0] : null;

    if ($dnc === null) {
        return false;
    }

    return [
        'count' => $count,
        'total'        => $dnc['total'],
        'comments'     => $dnc['comments'],
    ];
}
```

Returns the following:

```
$printout->getFailType($objectId)['count'] = 5
$printout->getFailType($objectId)['total'] = 20
$printout->getFailType($objectId)['comments'] = Contact unsubscribed via email
```

Comment: `$dnc     = isset($results) ? $results[0] : null;` - that doesn't look fishy to you, at all? It's screaming "only first record or nothing".

Comment: Oh, good catch!  I removed it and now the original record is simply tripled.  The other 4 rows still aren't seen.

Comment: Yep, and that's because of your query, you're grouping by a column. If you want to select *different* 5 records and retrieve the count at the same time, do the count part in a subquery / `JOIN`.

Comment: The comments column has 5 different rows, so in theory, it should display them all, no?  (Outside of this platform, this query works:
    `select count(lead_id) as total, reason, comments from ".$parameters['db_table_prefix']."lead_donotcontact GROUP BY comments ORDER BY total desc`  --not sure how to get the same to work within).

Comment: Try to run your query in MySQL terminal and see what happens. Usually that's the best way to approach these types of problems - see what MySQL returns using its terminal and then if the same doesn't come through in PHP - you identified where the problem is. However, if Doctrine and MySQL yield the same thing - then it's the query. Good luck!

Comment: Running via MySQL yielded success: 
Contact unsubscribed via email  20
There is a DNS loop  1
Unknown user or server  4
User unsubscribed.  1
Domain is Unknown  1

I think this is totally operator error.  I'm missing something or made a typo, or perhaps even my foreach() is broken? (Is foreach() needed? New to Symfony)
`foreach($printout->getFailType($objectId) as $fail):
         $html .= '<tr>
            <td>  '.$printout->getFailType($objectId)['total'].'</td>
            <td>'.$printout->getFailType($objectId)['comments'].'</td>
             </tr>';
        endforeach;`